# Magento Bundle products ,change drop-down

Tags: magento, bundle, product

I want to know  how to make "Please Choose..." as default drop-down label and default price to 0 for magneto bundle products with virtual products.

I want to see the price as 0 until select a quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be edit in the following file
     app\design\frontend\default\\template\bundle\catalog\product\view\type\bundle\option\select.phtml